# Why is it "es tut mir leid" and not "es tut mich leid"?

Tags: grammatical-case

I have been learning German for about a month now, and I am trying to understand the grammatical cases.

I read that we should say *es tut mir leid* to say *I am sorry* which I take to mean *it makes me sorry*. This confuses me; I thought that *es* is the subject and *I* (or *ich*) is the object. So, why do we not use the Accusative case for *I*, which is *mich*? Why do we use that dative *mir*?

Comment: My German instructor would always say Das tut mir leid. when we did not know an answer. That's too bad

Comment: I am not sure how to research this, but I think the expression may have evolved out of *jemandem ein Leid antun* (literal meaning *inflict a woe to someone*). As Tom Au explained, since the position of a direct object is already taken by *woe*, the inflictee has to become the indirect object. The German order of objects is the same as in English phrases that omit *to* for an indirect object, e.g. *give me [indirect obj.] the butter [direct obj.]*, which means the same as *give the butter to me*.

Comment: Just wait until you learn that it is warm/cold **to you**. But don't ever say "mir ist hungrig" ;-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"Es tut mir leid" can be translated as "It does hurt TO me."

Es is the the subject, tut is the verb, and mir is the INDIRECT object, while "hurt" is the direct object.

German uses quite of few of these indirect object constructions. "Mich," of course, is the direct object form but the German construction is NOT "It hurts me," (Subject verb direct object), but rather subject, verb, indirect object, direct object.

Comment: Aber in "Es geht mich nichts an" benutzt man "mich", nicht "mir".

Comment: I would say “it does (i.e.: causes) sorrow to me”

Comment: @WalterTross: I said," it does sorrow TO me," as opposed to "it does sorrow ME."

Answer (score 10):

German has verbs that take either the dative or the accusative.

The verb to be sorry "leid tun" is one that takes the dative.

Another dative verb for example is *helfen*:

> Er hat **mir** geholfen.

Or *zeigen*:

> Kannst du bitte **mir** den Weg zeigen?

Comment: or danken, "ich danke dir" ;)

Answer (score 3):

German language does not always follow the "subject - verb - object" rule.
To change the emphasis of a sentence, it can be rearranged:

> **Es** tut mir leid.

Meaning: "I am sorry for **it** (whatever I did)."
This is the most common form of this expression.

> **Mir** tut es leid.

Meaning: "**I** am sorry for it." (possible context: "but hey buddy, you should be sorry, too.")

similar:

> **Ich** danke Dir.

Meaning: "**I** thank you". This is the normal usage.

> **Dir** danke ich.

Meaning: "I thank **you**. (..., but not anyone else).

Comment: Yes, this is an answer, but it missed the question by a mile.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fixed expression now, but I would say that *leid*, or rather *Leid*, is the accusative (direct) object.

Compare with

> Es bereitet mir Schmerzen.

Comment: Just for fun consider also: "Es schmerzt mich."

Comment: And the reformed orthography recapitalised *leid* intermittently, before deciding to turn it into a connected verb *leidtun* … Ich glaube, es war der Zwiebelfisch, der dann gesagt hat »die armen Schüler können einem nur leid … Leid … also, die kann man nur bedauern«

Answer (score 0):

Es tut mir leid - Without having consulted reference books I would say:
"Es" refers to "that which you tell me/that which I hear". And the idea of the formula is:
That which I hear does/acts like something that gives **me (dative)** pain. 
In German: Das tut mir ein Leid an. A structure as in: Das macht mir Freude.

Often learners of a foreign language expect that the foreign language uses the same verb constructions and cases as the mother tongue. Unfortunately this isn't always the case or more pessimistically stated it is rarely the case.

Comment: Closely related languages such as German and English actually share a lot of constructions. Where constructions differ, this can often be explained by divergent development that fits into a general scheme such as the faster loss of case distinctions in English.